# What is the right java API to get filtered file list from ftp server

Tags: java, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I am just wondering how can I get the filtered file list from ftp server by maybe using wildcard in the parameter of some java api, I can't find the right api down here anyways, thanks a lot for any pointers!

http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

Even

Answer (score 2):

How about: http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#listFiles%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFileFilter%29

Comment: Although Apache commons provides a mechanism to filter files, this is done locally on client side. I mean, it actually lists all the files, then one by one sends them over a filtering method to return a boolean. I think, it would be better to do the filtering when listing the files on the server; something like the 'ls' command does on Linux platforms. then just get the desired file list which is more efficient and rational.

Comment: As far as I know, FTP (at least by default) does not support wildcards for the `LIST` command. The [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc959) only allows a path parameter. Clients are expected to parse (and filter) the results themselves. Also: There is no FTP command called `ls`.